# Spring Integration InboundChannelAdapter from xml to Java causing new polling console log

Tags: spring-integration, polling

Translated Spring Integration beans from xml to Java. Now I get new console log for every @InboundChannelAdapter which I didn't get before:

AbstractPollingEndpoint task-scheduler-7 DEBUG Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'

here's the initial config:

```
<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="the-file-input"
    directory="file:${import.file.dir.incomingFileDir}" channel="the-input" filter="customFilter" />
<si:channel id="the-input" />
<si:service-activator input-channel="the-input"
    output-channel="job-requests" ref="theJobLauncher" />

<bean id="theJobLauncher" class="com.example.POJO">

</bean>
```

New Java Config:

```
@Bean(name="theInput")
public MessageChannel manifestInputChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean(name="theFileInput")
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel="theInput")
public MessageSource<File> filesInboundChannelAdapter(@Value("${import.file.dir.incomingFileDir}") String incomingDirectory){
    FileReadingMessageSource sourceReader = new FileReadingMessageSource();
    sourceReader.setDirectory(new File(incomingDirectory));
    sourceReader.setFilter(customFileFilter);

    sourceReader.afterPropertiesSet();

    return sourceReader;
}


@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="theInput", outputChannel="jobRequestsChannel")
public Pojo theJobLauncher() {
    Pojo theJobLauncher = new Pojo();

    return theJobLauncher;
}
```

theJobJaucher reference a class with a @MessageEndpoint annotation and @ServiceActivator method

Is this new console log line normal or there is a problem with my configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are referring is exactly in the `AbstractPollingEndpoint`:

```
    if (message == null) {
        if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            this.logger.debug("Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'");
        }
        result = false;
    }
```

So, that mean definitely that you have somehow configured your logger for the `org.springframework.integration` category to `DEBUG` level.

This doesn't hurt though at all. You just don't have that logging configuration in your previous version.

You don't need to call `sourceReader.afterPropertiesSet();` yourself. That is an application context callback and it is indeed going to be called because you declare it as a bean.

Your `@ServiceActivator` definition is not correct. The `@Bean` annotation can be there only if you use a `MessageHandler` implementation.

You can move `@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="theInput", outputChannel="jobRequestsChannel")` to the `Pojo` method and just use a `@Bean` to declare a bean for that `Pojo`. Or since you use already `@MessageEndpoint` on that class, you can consider turn on `@ComponentScan` to let application context to pick up your class a a bean.

Another way is really like `MessageHandler` implementation with the call for your `Pojo`:

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="theInput", outputChannel="jobRequestsChannel")
public MessageHandler theJobLauncherServiceActivator(Pojo theJobLauncher) {
    return new MethodInvokingMessageHandler(theJobLauncher, (String) null);
}
```